# How to resolve the TestNG security vulnerability

Tags: testing, automation, frameworks, testng, test-framework

How to resolve TestNG Vulnerability?

I want to use TestNG in my automatiuon framework but due TestNG active vulnerabilities not able to use it duer to security issue

Answer (score 0):

As fer as I can see from latest [TestNG artifact](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng/7.7.1) there is the only vulnerability in one of the dependencies (`org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.33`).

[image]

However `org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.0` has that [vulnerability fixed](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml/2.0).

So your option would be to add that last version of `snakeyaml` to your root pom so that maven will take it in priority and hope that it is backward compatible with `1.33`